# Is there an SQLite equivelant to SHOW CREATE TABLE from MYSQL?

Tags: sqlite, create-table

I am working with sqlite3 and trying to get the create table statement of a table that I have modified since I have created it. However, the sql column in sqlite_master has the same create statement that was used to generate the table. I am looking for something more like the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE in MySQL where the create statement of the current table structure is provided. Is this possible? I use this create statement to help when checking if two tables are the same in structure. If they are not the same I then do a more in-depth check to see what exactly is different between them.

As mentioned before, I have tried to use sqlite_master's sql column. I have also checked the PRAGMA commands to see if what I was looking for existed.

I currently run

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master
```

This only gets the original create statement of the table, not the create statement needed to duplicate the table.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The sqlite3 command has two commands `.schema` and `.dump`. These output what is needed to duplicate the database. I don't know why it is so hard to get this information from the system tables where it should be accessed.

Comment: If you do anything with `ALTER TABLE`, those changes are reflected in the `CREATE TABLE` stored in the `sqlite_master` table.

Comment: Are these two commands able to be run in a query or do they have to be run through command line?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `.schema` to see table create statement.

```
.schema tablename
```

From [manual](https://sqlite.org/cli.html):

```
.schema ?PATTERN?        Show the CREATE statements matching PATTERN
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `sqlite_master` only contains the (normalized) original statement.

SQLite has no option to generate `CREATE TABLE` statements for you based on an existing table.

The `.dump` method is a feature by the SQLite shell. If you need to generate `CREATE TABLE` statements you'll need to implement it yourself.

You can refer to the dump_schema callback in shell.c from SQLite to see how the sqlite shell is generating the `.dump` output.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 shows this along with statements to re-create all the data. Use `.dump`.

Example output:

```
sqlite> .dump links
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "links" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "url" varchar, "description" text, "created_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO links VALUES(1,'http://graphql.org/','The Best Query Language','2021-05-13 13:48:15.649708','2021-05-13 13:48:15.649708');
INSERT INTO links VALUES(2,'http://dev.apollodata.com/','Awesome GraphQL Client','2021-05-13 13:48:19.405152','2021-05-13 13:48:19.405152');
COMMIT;
```

You're interested in the 3rd line, `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`